# Clicking outside a div -> Functions cancel each other out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div ("*.settings*") that I want to hide when clicked outside of, and I found the last piece of code here on StackOverflow. My problem is that when the div "*.settingsButton*" is clicked on, the div won't open if I use the last function.

I can see that the two functions cancel each other out, but have no idea on how to fix it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".settingsButton").click(function(){

    if(!$(".settings").hasClass("hide")) {
      $(".settings").addClass("hide");

    } else {
      $(".settings").removeClass("hide");
    }
 });

 $(document).on("click", function(event) {

   if(!$(event.target).closest(".settings").length) {
     if(!$(".settings").hasClass("hide")) {
       $(".settings").addClass("hide");
     }
   }
 });

});
```

**Edit:**
Here is the working code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".settingsButton").click(function(){
    $(".settings").toggleClass("hide");
  });

  $(document).on("click", function(event) {

    if(!$(event.target).closest(".settingsButton").length && !$(event.target).closest(".settings").length) {
        if(!$(".settings").hasClass("hide")) {
            $(".settings").addClass("hide");
        }
    }
});
```

});

I changed the first if statement in the first function to *.toggleClass*, and changed *closest.("settings")* to *closest.("settingsButton")* as @phts said.

The if statement underneath makes it so the open div won't close when it is clicked.

```
if(!$(event.target).closest(".settingsButton").length && !$(event.target).closest(".settings").length)
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v2ddjd7d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code didn't work due to one typo:

```
closest(".settings").
```

Should be

```
closest(".settingsButton").
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v2ddjd7d/2/

@ddlab's answer also works if `is(".settings"))` replace with `is(".settingsButton"))`

Answer (score 0):

(edited) This should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).on("click", function(event) {

   if(!$(event.target).is(".settingsButton")) {
       $(".settings").addClass("hide");
   } else $(".settings").toggleClass("hide");
 });

});
```

another edit, wrong class name settingsButton, now works